# How to change innerHTML of each item in a list of webelements with nested classes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, innerhtml

I am trying to make a javascript webextension that adds a couple numbers eg. "123" to the end of the inner text of a hyperlink text to each product on a shopping website, http://www.tomleemusic.ca

for example, if i go to this link, http://tomleemusic.ca/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=piano

I want to add some numbers to the end of each product's name. 
[name of product and its nested hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL8zd.png)

so far, I have attempted the following code but it does not produce any results. Thanks for helping :)

```js
var products= document.querySelector(".category-products, .products- 
grid category-products-grid itemgrid itemgrid-adaptive itemgrid-3col 
centered hover-effect equal-height");
var productslist = products.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (var i = 0; i < productslist.length; i++) {
    productslist[i].getElementsByClassName("product-name").innerHTML = 
productslist[i].getElementsByClassName("product-name").innerHTML + 
"1234";
}
```

Comment: sorry the code is indented weird, new to the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong and you should use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector for fetching all elements matching the query.

Below is the code required as per given site:

```
var productsListLink = document.querySelectorAll(".products-grid .item .product-name a:not(.product-image)");
for (var i = 0; i < productsListLink.length; i++) {
    var a = productsListLink[i];
    var name = a.innerHTML || "";
    name += "1234";
    a.innerHTML = name;
    a.setAttribute('title', name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to javascript and kind of coding in general so this was a huge help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found what you needed.

```
var products = document.querySelector(".category-products .products-grid.category-products-grid.itemgrid.itemgrid-adaptive.itemgrid-3col.centered.hover-effect.equal-height");
var productslist = products.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < productslist.length; i++) {
var productName = productslist[i].getElementsByClassName("product-name")[0].firstChild;
productName.innerHTML = productName.innerHTML + "1234";
}
```